# How to record all terminal input in bash, including interactive input?

Tags: bash, shell, unix, terminal

I'm trying to record all user input into the terminal to a file, so that it can be executed later.

I don't think I want to use `script` or `asciinema` package as the output includes lots of noise that is hard to execute again. Although if you can instruct how to clean up the output from those that'd be great to.

I am able to save all user input, except interactive inputs, into `recording.txt`, with this:

```
while :
do
    read -p ' → ' input
    echo $input >> recording.txt
    $input
done
```

e.g. if I run this then enter `ls`, that is added to `recording.txt`. However if I enter `npm init` (an interactive script), only `npm init` is added, not all the subsequent interactive input. Any advice on capturing everything would be greatly appreciated.

edit: by interactive I mean when you run a command and it prompts the user for more input - I want to include those inputs too.

Comment: So `script -I` ??

Comment: That seems to be an illegal operation? I tried it and got: `script: illegal option -- I`

Comment: ? What do you mean? The man page is clear `-I, --log-in file
              Log input to the file.  The log output is disabled if only
              --log-in specified.` o_O. whta is the output of `script --version`?

Comment: I'm on Mac OS not Linux. https://www.manpagez.com/man/1/script/. Should have clarified that. output of `script --version` is an error: `script: illegal option -- -
usage: script [-adkpqr] [-t time] [file [command ...]]`

Comment: @AndyCloke: Why **including** interactive input? Isn't any input from the terminal by definition interactive?

Comment: @AndyCloke : In your implementation, shouldn't it be `eval "$input"`? The variable input could, for example, contain metacharacters, which would need to be processed by the shell too.

Comment: Hm perhaps I'm using the wrong term. Maybe what I mean is input from cli/ sub-process too? e.g. when I run `npm init` it asks a load of follow up prompts at the terminal, and I want to include the responses to those too. Does that make sense?

Comment: Not for me. Are the prompts really sent directly to and written from the tty, or are they written to stdout and read from stdin (and these channels are, of course, connected to a terminal)? I don't have experience with `npm`, but if it really insists in reading directly from the terminal, and you can't disable this behaviour (which might be the case, but would be highly unusual), you would have to create a pseudo terminal. At least you would need some knowledge of the internals of `npm`; but I think any sane package manager is written in a way that it can be scripted.

Comment: @user1934428 "In your implementation, shouldn't it be eval "$input"? " -  it could well be - I'm v new to bash scripting! thanks

Comment: Thanks, yeah so `npm init` was just an example - I'm actually trying to create a versatile script that can record any set of commands. So I want to avoid coupling it to the internals of npm init. Do you think that's possible?

Comment: It has not been mentioned yet, but previously executed commands can be read using `history`  command.

Comment: Unfortunately `history` omits the interactive input (e.g. after running a cli like `npm init`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not care too much about prompts,

```
tee file | bash
```

would give you what you want. For example:

```
$ tee file | bash
ls
file  this
ed konijn
konijn: No such file or directory
a
wiep
.
1,$p
wiep
w
5
q
ls
file  konijn  this
cat konijn
wiep
```

gives the log in `file`:

```
ls
ed konijn
a
wiep
.
1,$p
w
q
ls
cat konijn
```

Comment: Add `-i` to `bash -i` and you will see a prompt, but there will be a problem when exiting the shell.

Comment: yes, but it also seems to hang when `ed` is started. So that is why I ommitted it.